ERROR: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported
I am training a deep learning model on the purpose of classifying images of playing cards using convolutional nueral networks. This is the my model , it's architecture and training loop
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3, padding = 1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3, padding = 1)
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)
        self.flat = nn.Flatten()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32 * 56 * 56, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 133)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = self.flat(x)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = F.softmax(x, dim = 1)
        return x

model = Model()
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model.to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.001)
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
def train(model, train_dataloader, val_dataloader, optimizer, criterion, epochs):
    try:
        loss_history = []
        val_loss_history = []
        # iterating over epochs
        min_val_loss = float('inf')
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            epoch_train_loss = 0.0
            epoch_val_loss = 0.0
            # switching the model to training mode
            model.train()

            for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
                # moving the data and target to GPU
                data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)

                # zeroing the gradients
                optimizer.zero_grad()

                # forward pass
                output = model(data)

                # calculating the loss
                loss = criterion(output, target.unsqueeze(-1).float())

                # backward pass
                loss.backward()
                epoch_train_loss += loss.item()

                # updating the weights
                optimizer.step()

            with torch.inference_mode():
                # switching the model to evaluation mode
                model.eval()
                # iterating over the validation set
                for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(val_dataloader):
                    data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
                    # forward pass
                    output = model(data)
                    # calculating the loss
                    loss = criterion(output, target.unsqueeze(-1).float())
                    epoch_val_loss += loss.item()

            if epoch_val_loss < min_val_loss:
                min_val_loss = epoch_val_loss
                torch.save(model.state_dict(), '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/cards_classification_best_model.pth')

            epoch_train_loss /= len(train_dataloader)
            epoch_val_loss /= len(val_dataloader)
            loss_history.append(epoch_train_loss)
            val_loss_history.append(epoch_val_loss)
            print(f'epoch {epoch} loss : {epoch_train_loss:.4f}, epoch {epoch} validation loss {epoch_val_loss:.4f}')
        return loss_history, val_loss_history

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Training interrupted by the user.")
        print('model saved at the epoch with least validaion loss')
        return loss_history, val_loss_history


I initiated training loop using following line:
loss, val_loss = train(model, train_dataloader, val_dataloader, optimizer, loss_fn, 10)

this is error i got from it:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-a66cbbca6c6f> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 loss, val_loss = train(model, train_dataloader, val_dataloader, optimizer, loss_fn, 10)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   3084     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   3085         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3086     return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
   3087 
   3088 

RuntimeError: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported

please drag me out of this, and thanks in advance for it.
